# How to read text from an application window using pywinauto

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

I have a python code which opens a SSH session using Putty and passes a command to reboot a remote machine using pywinauto.
I want to read the text from the putty terminal after typing the password and compare it
Is there a way I can do it?
Below is the piece of code for the same

```
    app_Putty = application.Application()
    app_Putty.start_("C:\Users\debajyoti.bose\Downloads\putty.exe")
    app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys(IP)
    app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys("{TAB}"+"22")
    app_Putty.top_window_().RadioButton4.Click()
    app_Putty.top_window_().OpenButton.Click()
    time.sleep(10)
    app_Putty.top_window_().NoButton.Click()
    time.sleep(2)
    app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys(user+"{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(3)
    app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys(password+"{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(3)
    app_Putty.top_window_().TypeKeys("/bin/reboot"+"{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(5)
    app_Putty.kill_()
    time.sleep(120)
```

I am using pywinauto v0.4.0
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the output of command `app_Putty.top_window_().PrintControlIdentifiers()` before killing the app.

Comment: Hi Ryabov, 
Thanks for the reply. I already tried that and it is not printing the console output. Actually I need to read the response from the console when a wrong password is entered which is as below: 
**root@192.168.1.18's password: Access denied root@192.168.1.18's password:**
 All I get when I use that command is:
` Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\abc.def\reboot - Copy (6).py", line 88, in <module> app_Putty().top_window().PrintControlIdentifiers() TypeError: 'Application' object is not callable`

Comment: Please remove brackets from `app_Putty` instance. :)
Just copy the command from my previous comment and run before `app_Putty.kill_()`.

Comment: Hi Ryabov,
I tried exactly the same and this time got only a null string after PrintControlIdentifiers[].

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's try `app_Putty.top_window_().WindowText()`. If it fails your mission looks impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture directly like this from what I can tell, but I had to find a workaround, and the one I found was this

```
#clear the buffer with alt space menu 
app.window(title='PuTTY - Title').type_keys('% l',with_spaces=True)

#copy the buffer to clipboard 
app.window(title='PuTTY - Title').type_keys('% o',with_spaces=True)
```

I was having to do this because the putty.log file was missing the selection indicator icon (asterisk) on the screen when it was logging output and I needed a way to know which item was selected to move up or down.